# Reading from the registry – Involves disk? Limitation on reading access?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

Does reading involve the disk or is it RAM only?

Is it always available for reading, or are there any limitations such as certain users who will have demoted security and will not be able to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registry is stored on disk, but will be cached (to some extent) so you are basically reading from disk though there will be times when you'll get the cached version.

While, in general, all users have read only access to the registry, there will be parts (other user profiles, for example) that won't be accessible.

You should always have read only access to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (with the exception of  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY` are restricted and can only be read with local system privilege) and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.

Comment: Exceptions: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY are restricted and can only be read with local system privilege.